# How to give headings for each toolbar section in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I need to design a custom tool bar as same as below image. For that I have used following lines of code:

```
m_ptrFileToolBar = new QToolBar("File",theUi->toolBar);
m_ptrNewAct = new QAction(QIcon(":/res/images/New.png"), tr("&New"), this);
m_ptrNewAct->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::New);
m_ptrNewAct->setStatusTip(tr("Create a new file"));
m_ptrFileToolBar->addAction(m_ptrNewAct);
```

It is showing only tool bar actions. But I need to give headings to each tool bar section. How do I do it in `Qt`?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to subclass [QWidgetAction](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidgetaction.html) and reimplement [QWidgetAction::createWidget()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidgetaction.html#createWidget) function

```
QWidget *myWidgetAction::createWidget(QWidget *parent)
{
   QWidget *myWidget = new QWidget(parent);
   QAction *act1 = new QAction(QIcon(":/1.png"),tr("New"),myWidget);
   QAction *act2 = new QAction(QIcon(":/2.png"),tr("Open"),myWidget);
   QAction *act3 = new QAction(QIcon(":/3.png"),tr("Create"),myWidget);
   QToolBar *toolbar = new QToolBar(myWidget);
   toolbar->addAction(act1);
   toolbar->addAction(act2);
   toolbar->addAction(act3);
   QLabel *title = new QLabel("test");
   QGridLayout *grid = new QGridLayout(myWidget);
   myWidget->setLayout(grid);
   grid->addWidget(title,0,0,1,0,Qt::AlignCenter);
   grid->addWidget(toolbar,1,0,1,0,Qt::AlignCenter);
   return myWidget;
}
```

Then you can add `myWidgetAction` object to toolbar

```
m_ptrFileToolBar = new QToolBar("File",theUi->toolBar);
myWidgetAction *widgetAction = new myWidgetAction(this);
m_ptrFileToolBar->addAction(widgetAction);
```